# How to apply result to html page by using jquery ui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I wanna create a hidden input tag automatically by using jquery ui (dialog). It's excuting correctly. But the result cannot be applied to html page.

I design a button to call dialog box, like this:

```
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Click me" />
<div id="dialog-box" title="My dialog">
<span>Any text here...</span>
</div>
```

and a `div` to store the result:

```
<div class="result">
</div>
```

My script code is:

```
function myFunction()
    {
        $(".result").append("<input id=\"CategoryId\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"abc\" />");
        $("#dialog-box").dialog("close");        
    }

    $("#dialog-box").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 100,
        width: 250,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": myFunction,
            "Cancel": function () {
                $("#dialog-box").dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close: function () {
        }
    });
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        $("#dialog-box").dialog("open");
    });
```

When I view page source, nothing was created. I have tested it by putting this line into **myFunction()**: `alert("Category id: " + $("#CategoryId").val());`

It showed me the result: `Category id: abc`

But the `div` on page source still is:

```
<div class="result">
</div>
```

I have pasted these lines on the top:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Can you tell me why and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: How do you check it is not added? HTML source isn't updated because this is what returns server, not reflecting any change done client side. To check it, inspect element in your browser instead. That's said, beware IDs must be unique on document conetext, your logic could bring invalid HTML markup if dialog `ok` button is clicked more than once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not have any problem and it is working well and adding an hidden input to `.result`

**Why you can't see the `hidden input` source code?**

Browser can't show you dynamycly added item (items what added by JavaScript) and if you want to see it you should use **Inspect Element** or **firebug** (Firefox).

let me show you an Image:

[image]

And see this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rw7s9hr0/3/)

**Edit:** Its really better to see what are you doing, I suggest you to change hidden to text until the test end.  Now you see what you have after clicking on OK that is in **dialog**.

What I will do here is just a little testing, I want when **OK** from dialog clicked an alert show what is in **`hidden input`** value. I mean inside `my_function` (before that change the class `result` to id `result`):

```
var theVal
function myFunction()
    {
        $(".myresult").html("<input id=\"CategoryId\" type=\"text\" value=\"abc\" />");
        $("#dialog-box").dialog("close"); 
         theVal=$(".myresult input").val();
         alert(theVal);
    }
```

You can send this variable with Ajax or you can send it by a form.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how to convert `dynamic item` (as you mean) to `normal item`. I wanna re-use the value of hidden input tag in other place. So if it cannot be showed on page source as normally, I won't be detected.

Comment: you can define variable, or if you are going to submit. you can create a `<form>` and insert `hidden input` to form then submit it.

Comment: @Kevin OK, Time to test. What do you think about my answer?

Comment: Im testing with your advice. I have created a form and added `var form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      myFunction();
    });` But still not working :(( The `hidden input` cannot be showed.

Comment: @Kevin Take a look at edit please. if it's not what you need let me know and will help you again (if you need)

Answer (score 0):

try changing result class to an id instead, class search in jquery returns an array.

```
  $("#result").append("<input id=\"CategoryId\" type=\"hidden\"       value=\"abc\" />");
```

and

```
<div id="result">
```

or if it needs to be a class and is the first result class element then use

```
  $(".result")[0].append("<input id=\"CategoryId\" type=\"hidden\"       value=\"abc\" />");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree with the answer of LASH... your code seems good not need to change anything, to see text inside div result use inspect element instead of view source.

Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Click me" />
<div id="dialog-box" title="My dialog">
    <span>Any text here...</span>
</div>

<div class="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction()
    {   
        $(".result").html("<input id=\"CategoryId\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"abc\" />");
        $("#dialog-box").dialog("close");        
    }

    $("#dialog-box").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 250,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": myFunction,
            "Cancel": function () {
                $("#dialog-box").dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close: function () {
        }
    });
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        $("#dialog-box").dialog("open");
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```